# Change detection for objects in with observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

Imagine the following subscribe of an observable:

```
this.todosStore.subscribe((todos) => {
        this.todoContent = todos.content;
        this.todoVisibility = todos.visibility;
    });
```

In order to make the subscribe work I currently return a cloned object after I have changed a property:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE:
        action.payload.id = state.id++;
        state.content.push(action.payload);

        return _.cloneDeep(state);
```

Is there any alternative or better way to make the subscribe work? For example can/should I get rid of _.cloneDeep(state) somehow?

Comment: Are you using the `cloneDeep` to force a change-detection where no changes have happened? Or are you mutating object, where you should work with immutables?

Comment: I updated the question based on olsn's comment. Changes are happening, but I guess as the reference of the object does not change, the subscribe function is not triggert. So should I work with immutables? Does this mean that I should clone the state straight from the beginning and return the cloned and modified object?

Comment: @Paolo What changes are happening, where, when? You have to provide some code. Share code necessary to reproduce the issue, what current behavior is, what expected behavior is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely rely on `Object.assign` to get new references (which do trigger change detection)

So in your example it would look like this:

`switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE:
        let newContentElement = action.payload
        newContentElement.id = state.id++
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
             content: [..state.content, newContentElement]
        })`

I would try to avoid using libraries for making the copy. It forces you to a better understanding and most of the time Object.assign is enough anyways.

Comment: littleStudent is right, use Object.assign. One thing tho, with Redux, with a given param you should be able to guess the output but here you increment an ID from the reducer. I don't think this is a good idea. If you really need to compute that ID on client side, you should create a service (singleton) with a get method that returns a new ID every time and then pass the object with the new ID to the reducer.